# Summoned to another world with four(?) classmates. Protagonist is separated but ends up with a group of female companions including a goddess

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm trying to locate an Isekai manga. In this one, the main character is summoned to another world with 4(?) of his other classmates, and they all have special skills.

Through some weird turn of events, the main character somehow gets separated from the his classmates. All his classmates are worried about him, specifically one of the female characters. The main character, however, was doing just fine and he met a harem of women including some sort of overpowered goddess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is *[Makikomarete Isekai Teni suru Yatsu wa, Taitei Cheat](https://myanimelist.net/manga/96827/Makikomarete_Isekai_Teni_suru_Yatsu_wa_Taitei_Cheat)*, or *He is a matchless warrior in different-dimension world!!*.

The main character, Koyusai Takanashi, and his 4 friends are summoned to another world to be heroes. The 5 of them go out to get a handle on how their bodies work in this new world. During that, they are attacked by some mud creatures and Koyusai gets teleported to a ruined temple with a computer in it. Koyusai's friends are worried about him after he disappears. One of the women had a crush on him and constantly worries about him.

Koyusai then goes around gaining female companions, including one that was summoned by a different companion. The summoned one is a "Deity Class Evil God".

Comment: Yep, it was this one exactly! Thanks man fr. It's just as dookie as I remembered it being