# Isekai manga where mc is starts with being weak

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai, erotica

This was an ecchi manga in which the main character and some of his friends are transported to another world, but the MC was summoned by mistake because he was holding his girlfriend's hand but he is the weakest among that group. One day two girls were attacked by a monster and in order to save them the mc died but he went to some place where there was a pc and changes his stats and become op.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Makikomarete Isekai Teni suru Yatsu wa, Taitei Cheat](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/makikomarete-isekai-teni-suru-yatsu-wa-taitei-cheat)* as per [Summoned to another world with four(?) classmates. Protagonist is separated but ends up with a group of female companions including a goddess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251592/summoned-to-another-world-with-four-classmates-protagonist-is-separated-but?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> The main character, Koyusai Takanashi, and his 4 friends are summoned to another world to be heroes. The 5 of them go out to get a handle on how their bodies work in this new world. During that, they are attacked by some mud creatures and Koyusai gets teleported to a ruined temple with a computer in it. Koyusai's friends are worried about him after he disappears. One of the women had a crush on him and constantly worries about him.
>
> Koyusai then goes around gaining female companions, including one that was summoned by a different companion. The summoned one is a "Deity Class Evil God".

Comment: Thanx man this is the one I m searching for